# ascii character limit is 255?

Tags: c, ascii

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int i=369;
    printf("%c",i);
    getch();
}



O/p
===
q
```

Here , getting 'q' as a output .

My doubt is the ascii character limit is 255 . But why it is giving 'q' as output ?

Comment: Well, if you look at a ascii chart: http://www.asciitable.com/ You will see the limit is 128.

Comment: @Scotty Bauer  I thought the limit was 127.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `"%c"` in `printf()` takes the `int` parameter `369` and converts it to an `unsigned char` which has the value `369 & 255` or `113`.  Character code 113 corresponds to `'q'` on a system using ASCII encoding.  Thus `'q'` is printed.

C11dr §7.21.6.1 8  c conversion specifier
"If no l length modifier is present, the int argument is converted to an unsigned char, and the resulting character is written."

---

[Edit]
Typical C systems have an 8-bit `char` which allows for 256 combinations, hence the above `& 255` (Some systems have other `char` sizes).  Typical C systems assign values 0 to 127 to the ASCII character set - which is *only* defined for codes 0 to 127.  The text that may print out with values outside that range varies.

Answer (score 8):

It's being cast to a byte. 369 % 256 = 113 = 'q'

Answer (score 0):

ascii's limit is 255, however 369=0000 0001 0111 0001, while q's ascii code is 0111 0001, see the last 8 bits? You got it!

Comment: Typical `UCHAR_MAX` is 255 and that why the 369 is truncated to 8 bits.  [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) range is 0 to 127.

Comment: To be more precise, the extended ASCII is 0-255